# Detect if cursor is hidden on Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, mouse-cursor

Is there a programmatic, non-private-API way to detect whether the mouse cursor is hidden on Mac OS X? (As occurs, for example, when typing into a text field.)

`NSCursor` has `hide` and `unhide` but no `isHidden`. I'm wondering if there is some other API which might do what I want. C-based APIs are fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try `CGCursorIsVisible()` (returns a `BOOL`).

Comment: Note: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646273/osx-how-to-tell-if-cursor-is-visible) seems to indicate that the solution here is deprecated.