# OSX - How to tell if cursor is visible

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, mouse-cursor

I understand that this question has already been answered:

[Detect if cursor is hidden on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026660/detect-if-cursor-is-hidden-on-mac-os-x)

But at this point, the function "CGCursorIsVisible" has been deprecated.  According to the help literature, there is no replacement.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGCursorIsVisible

When using the hide and show functions (CGDisplayHideCursor / CGDisplayShowCursor), no reference to the cursor's visibility is returned.  Although a show / hide counter is maintained by quartz, there's no way of accessing that value.

So, how do we find out if the cursor is visible or not?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the very same problem and could not find a valid answer to this problem.

I solved it by implementing a counter which is set to 0 when my application starts. I increase it everytime I hide the cursor and then I can unhide while the `_counter != 0`.

Your Mac seems to have an own counter for each application... So if your application is not in foreground and it uses the `[NSCursor hide]` command, it will still be visible but become invisible, when your app becomes keyWindow again.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a little bit late, but I recently stumbled upon a similar issue. One way to solve this problem is to push an empty cursor onto the cursor stack instead of calling `NSCursor.hide()` like this:

```
let myCursor = NSCursor.init(image: NSImage.init(size: NSSize(width: 1, height: 1)), hotSpot: NSPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
myCursor.set()
```

At a later point in time you can then just push the normal arrow cursor with `NSCursor.arrow.set()` or `NScursor.arrow.push()`.

This way you don't have the issue of keeping track of the hide/unhide count.
Theoretically you should also be able to check the reference of `NSCursor.current` against `myCursor` and see if you still have the *invisible* cursor (I have not checked this though).